# VB - How to sort results from database in ascending or descending order

Tags: sql, vb.net, sorting

I have this Select statement that works fine:

```
rsCurrent.Source = "SELECT Calibrations.Cust_Ref, Calibrations.Rec_Date, Instruments.Inst_ID, Instruments.Description, Instruments.Model_no, Instruments.Manufacturer, Instruments.Serial_no, Instruments.Status, Instruments.Cust_Acc_No  FROM Instruments INNER JOIN Calibrations ON Instruments.Inst_ID = Calibrations.Inst_ID  WHERE Instruments.Cust_Name = '" & Session("MM_Username") & "' AND Instruments.Cust_Acc_No = '" & Session("MM_Password") & "' AND Instruments.Cust_Acc_No = '" + Replace(rsCurrent__MMColParam, "'", "''") + "' AND Instruments.Status IN ('E','F','G','H','I','K','L','M','N');"
```

I tried different approaches to try and set my records in descending order looking up for Calibrations.Rec_Date

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: see ORDER BY in your SQL manual

Comment: And all the warning lights come on at the same time. Sql Injection error...., Sql Injection error.... , Sql Injection error....

Comment: @Steve Your comment right when I was thinking I'm too paranoid!

Comment: Not worry, it's not death or life, it is just buggy code unless it is used to fly a plane.....

Comment: Please don't say that! Seen something like this, I won't board any planes in the near future.

Comment: Think you should see the source code that I have been given :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try,

```
rsCurrent.Source = "SELECT Calibrations.Cust_Ref, Calibrations.Rec_Date, Instruments.Inst_ID, Instruments.Description, Instruments.Model_no, Instruments.Manufacturer, Instruments.Serial_no, Instruments.Status, Instruments.Cust_Acc_No  FROM Instruments INNER JOIN Calibrations ON Instruments.Inst_ID = Calibrations.Inst_ID  WHERE Instruments.Cust_Name = '" & Session("MM_Username") & "' AND Instruments.Cust_Acc_No = '" & Session("MM_Password") & "' AND Instruments.Cust_Acc_No = '" + Replace(rsCurrent__MMColParam, "'", "''") + "' AND Instruments.Status IN ('E','F','G','H','I','K','L','M','N') ORDER BY Calibrations.Rec_Date DESC;"
```

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp

You may want to try ORDER BY DATE(Calibrations.Rec_Date)

Comment: Hi AFM, This was a great solution, I tried a similar approach but had a sintax error.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Hope I will be able to help others at some point once that I'm new to stack overflow